# How do i call an external function?

Tags: c++, dlopen

I have code i'm trying to write, I have a void function, info.

```
void info(char *,char *);
```

This, I'm trying to call from my main function in a separate file. I want to use dlopen to open a so file. How would i call the function: info. From my other file?

I'm trying to use

```
info("testing: ","Success");
```

I get an undefined reference error on my info function.

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a linker error, not a compiler error. Reread about the basics of compiling and linking to double check how to link all your translation units.

Comment: The signature of the function does not provide enough information to say how to call it. However, if you don't know the function's requirements, then you should not use it. So the solution is, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual path is something like this:

```
/* Set up a typedef for the function pointer to make the code nicer */
tyepdef void(*Info_ptr)(char*, char*);
/* Get the function, lib must be the dlopened library.*/
Info_ptr info;
info = (Info_ptr)dlsym( lib, "info");
/* Use the function pointer */     
(*info)("testing: ", "Success");
```

Take al ook here for a tute: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/

Comment: I found out that now its saying 'undefined symbol: info'

Comment: Check your .so to make sure you've got the symbol you expect in it. YOu can use `nm` to help you with that. If your `info` function is C++ too, then you'll need to set it up using `extern "C"` like in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for this, It helped me allot once i fixed the function info.